# Как вызывать справку по функции горячими клавишами в VSCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Пишу код на typescript и при наведении курсора на какую-либо функцию появляется подсказка либо просто с аргументами, их типом и типом возвращаемого значения, либо к этому ниже добавляется описание функции/метода.

Собственно есть ли горячие клавиши, чтобы я поставив курсор внутри названия определенного встроенного метода/функции и нажав сочетание горячих клавиш мог увидеть эту справку по методу/функции (может есть возможность назначить сочетание клавиш на это событие)?

P.S.
F1 не помогает - вызывает поиск по всему функционалу редактора.

P.P.S.
Про отображение очень краткой справки по Ctrl+Space я знаю, но она очень краткая и без подсветки:

Вот, что отображается, когда я нажимаю Ctrl+Space
[image]

***А вот, что отображается, когда я навожу курсор (на это я хочу как-то повесить горячие клавиши)***
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать `Alt+F12`, чтоб посмотреть определение функции
[image: peek definition]